# Sliding menu Fragment getContext return null

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu, universal-image-loader

Im using sliding menu in android and I'm having a lot of trouble to get the context throught the Fragment.
The Main Activity:

```
    slide = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slide.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slide.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slide.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    slide.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    slide.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
    slide.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slide.setMenu(R.layout.left_panel);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.leftPanel, new LeftPanel()).commit();
```

I tried using:

```
Context context;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.d("Spread",activity.toString());
    context = activity;
}
```

and

```
   this.getActivity()
```

It always return **null**.
Whats the matter here?

EDIT: Use of the Context:

```
        com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader imageLoader =  com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();                           \
   imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

    DisplayImageOptions conf = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).build();
        if (((ParseFile)user.get("profilePicture")).getUrl() != null) imageLoader.displayImage(((ParseFile)user.get("profilePicture")).getUrl(), profPic, conf, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {                  
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,FailReason failReason) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

            }
        });*/
```

Comment: Where in your fragment's code are you calling getActivity() or using context that it's crashing?

Comment: Where in your fragment's lifecycle is that called, though?

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {} @dymmeh

Comment: This question is very undervalued. This happens all the time, and should be resolved by the Android team ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your  code change: `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.leftPanel, new LeftPanel(MainActivity.this)).commit();`

```
LeftPanel{

Context  context;

LeftPanel(Context c)
{
        this.context = c;
}

}
```

You will get the right context in this case, hope this helps

Comment: I thought we can't use constructor on fragments. But using the supress it's all ok! Thanks @lordzden

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on where you are trying to use the context.  It is possible that the `onAttach()` hasn't fired before you actually try and use that context.  Therefore, your `Context context;` ends up being null.  It's hard to tell without some additional code, so that is the only assumption that I can make thus far.

Comment: I edited the question. The onAttach() is called and the activity is not null. but when i use it, it crashes and tell me that context is null.